# Useing a PoE RJ45 ICM Magnetics but not using it for PoE?

Tags: transformer, ethernet, magnetics, poe, rj45

I plan on using the [Bel G27-122T-015](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Bel-Magnetic-Solutions/G27-122T-015?qs=hWgE7mdIu5TDzG1nxJSWtQ%3D%3D) (PoE ICM RJ45) but I don't need it for PoE. Can I just leave these pins unconnected? The ICM already has an internal Bob Smith termination.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course you can.

It simply provides the PoE connections while a non-PoE magjack just does not provide the connections.